# eclipse rcp : more powerful table widget?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

It seems swt table does't allow us to operate on multiple cells ?My application need a feature like this "select **a range of cells**, then copy cell text to excel, or paste text **into cells**".I think this will be a handy feature.

Any solution on this ?

best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the nat table component, see http://www.nattable.org/drupal/
This component has many features that are not covered by the basic SWT table widget

Answer (score 0):

For people reaching this, NatTable has been moved to Eclipse Nebula.

https://eclipse.org/nebula

It also contains Grid and XViewer as table alternatives.